# How do I safely take in user input to build another string in my Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, sqlconnection

I need to safely prepare a string that uses user input. I'm using a flutter package called [sql_conn](https://pub.dev/packages/sql_conn) to communicate with a SQL database. This is a temporary solution until we build a web server to take in all calls.

This is an example of how a SQL request is sent:

```
var connectionAllowedResult = await SqlConn.readData("declare @Allowed bit declare @Status nvarchar(4000) exec spHandheldConnectionAllowed '$username', '$ipAddress', '$dbName', @Allowed output, @Status output");
```

How do I safely prepare this so that a user can't maliciously insert their own SQL statement?

Answer (score 0):

The package validation_chain on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/validation_chain) might help you out. There are great examples of using custom functions to provide validation.

Doing input validation when the user inputs the field and before the sql statement would be a start.

Another suggestion is to use types that disallow improper input. Instead of storing ip address as a string, store it as a list of 4 int's, etc.